# How can I disable transparency throughout the UI?

Tags: settings, themes, pantheon-terminal, accessibility

Transparency makes the text hard to read, and has zero benefit that I've ever been able to see. How do I turn it off? At least in Pantheon Terminal, ideally wherever it might occur.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In order to turn off transparency, open a terminal session and run the following commands, depending on your version of elementary OS:

## 0.4 Loki

**Turn off transparency in WingPanel**

```
gsettings set org.pantheon.desktop.wingpanel use-transparency false
```

**Turn off transparency in Terminal**

```
gsettings set org.pantheon.terminal.settings background "rgba(37, 46, 50, 1.0)"
```

## 0.3 Freya

**Turn off transparency in WingPanel**

```
gsettings set org.pantheon.desktop.wingpanel auto-adjust-alpha false
gsettings set org.pantheon.desktop.wingpanel background-alpha 1.0
```

For this change to have an effect, WingPanel needs to be reloaded (log off & log on again).

**Turn off transparency in Terminal**

```
gsettings set org.pantheon.terminal.settings opacity 100
```

---

## Reset to default

Use the `gsettings reset` command to restore the default value of a setting, for example to turn back on WingPanel transparency in 0.4 Loki:

```
gsettings reset org.pantheon.desktop.wingpanel use-transparency
```

Comment: To restart wingpanel you just have to kill it, and cerbere will restart it.

Comment: on juno 0.5 i receive an error: gsettings set org.pantheon.desktop.wingpanel use-transparency false